# Incorrect Reference for Figures

Tags: cross-referencing

I have two figures (and a table), and while the table references correctly, the two references for figures both display figure 2, but the two captions are figure 1 and figure 2.

```
\begin{figure}[!bp]
\label{fig:setup1}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{figure 1.png}
\caption{Cold and hot water experiment setup}
\end{figure}

.... see Figure \ref{fig:setup1}......

\begin{figure}
\label{fig:setup2}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{updated figure 2.png}
\caption{Hot water and ice cube experiment setup}
\end{figure}

..... see Figure \ref{fig:setup2}....
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Move `\label` after `\caption` in each case. (And always `\label` must go after the thing it labels.)

Comment: @cfr works! Thank you!